# ElasticSearch - clarification around `top_terms_boost_N` rewrite parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

After reading the documentation, I haven't quite wrapped my head around how the rewrite parameter `top_terms_boost_N` works.

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html):

> Assigns each matching document a relevance score equal to the boost
> parameter.
>
> This method changes the original query to a bool query. This bool
> query contains a should clause and term query for each matching term.
>
> The final bool query only includes term queries for the top N terms.
>
> You can use this method to avoid exceeding the clause limit in the
> indices.query.bool.max_clause_count setting.

Example. Say I'm querying with the string `A B C D E F G`, and I set `N` to `2`, so `top_terms_boost_2` is used as the rewrite parameter.

- Does that mean Elastic will take two of the terms from the provided string? E.g. `C` and `F`.
- How does elastic decide what constitutes a "top" term, is it term frequency?
- Why is it important that elastic `Assigns each matching document a relevance score equal to the boost parameter`?